# TypeScript doesn't seem to check types on a class instance property

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a `Provider` class, and I create an instance of it with some functions, but when I try to access any of those functions, TypeScript doesn't check the parameters of those functions, I believe I may have done something wrong, or some change could be made so TypeScript does check the types.

My Provider class:

```
export class Provider {
  name: string;
  referencedAs: string;
  description?: string;
  functions: {
    [name: string]: {
      description?: string;
      run: Function;
    };
  };

  constructor(
    name: string,
    referencedAs: string,
    functions: {
      [name: string]: {
        description?: string;
        run: Function;
      };
    },
    description?: string
  ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.referencedAs = referencedAs;
    this.description = description ?? 'Description not specified';
    this.functions = functions;
  }
}
```

My class instance:

```
export const TOTPProvider = new Provider(
  'TOTP',
  'totp',
  {
    verify: {
      description: 'Verify a TOTP code, returns true if the code is valid.',
      run: (secret: string, code: number, leniency?: number): boolean => {
        var valid = false;
        var thisGen = gen(secret);
        var prevGen = gen(secret, Date.now() - 30000);
        var existedFor = 30 - prevGen.remaining;
        console.log(existedFor);

        if (thisGen.code === code) valid = true;
        if (leniency > 0 && existedFor < leniency * 1000) console.log('yeehaw');

        return valid;
      },
    },
    generate: {
      description: 'Verify a TOTP code',
      run: (secret: string, code: number): boolean => {
        return gen(secret).code === code;
      },
    },
  },
  'TOTP (Time based One-Time Passwords), a modification of HOTP (Counter based One-Time Passwords), uses a SHA-1 HMAC hash of the current time (rounded to the nearest 30 seconds) with a secret key, to produce a 6 digit authentication code to be used for 2FA (Two-Factor Authentication).'
);
```

TypeScript doesn't complain when I call `TOTPProvider.functions.generate.run();` without any parameters, even though it should, node does throw an error because secret is undefined, what have I done wrong here?

Comment: Of course, it won't. `TOTPProvider` is defined as a `Provider`, so TOTPProvider.functions.generate.run is defined as a `Function`.

Comment: @htn Hmm, is it because I defined the type as `Function` and not as `(secret: function, code: number) => boolean` that typescript won't check the parameter types?

Comment: yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a generic class:

```
export class Provider<
    F extends Record<
        string,
        {
            description?: string;
            run: Function;
        }
    >
> {
    name: string;
    referencedAs: string;
    description?: string;
    functions: F;

    constructor(
        name: string, 
        referencedAs: string, 
        functions: F, 
        description?: string
    ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.referencedAs = referencedAs;
        this.description = description ?? 'Description not specified';
        this.functions = functions;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried using a generic inteface, but I still get the same error, my code: https://hasteb.in/budezafu.ts

Comment: Your `class Provider` is not generic and it expects the same type for every function. To have different types with type checking you need some form of `class Provider<F> {functions: F}`

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my problem!